# How does the public key exchange between a client and server happen for RSA?

Tags: c#, rest, aes, client-server, rsa

I am very new to cryptography and just playing around encrypting the content that my server sends to my client.I have the RSA encryption-decryption class written for the client and the server applications.In the server response to a GET request from the client,it encrypts the content and sends it to the client but the decryption doesn't work and I get the following exception in the server application -
`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Key not valid for use in specified state'`
The following is my code for RSA encryption and decryption

```
namespace HttpClientSample
{
    public class RsaEncryption
    {
        private static RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        private RSAParameters _privateKey;
        private RSAParameters _publicKey;

        public RsaEncryption()
        {
            _privateKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
            _publicKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);
        }
        public string GetPublicKey()
        {
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
            xs.Serialize(sw, _publicKey); //?
            return sw.ToString();
        }

        public string Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            csp.ImportParameters(_publicKey);
            var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
            var cypher = csp.Encrypt(data, false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cypher);

        }
        public string Decrypt(string cypherText)
        {
            var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);
            csp.ImportParameters(_privateKey);
            var plainText = csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
        }
    }
```

This is the same piece of code in the client side.But how is the public key exchange done? after the keys(public and private) are generated at the server side,how will the client generate the private key needed to decrypt the message coming from the server?Do we need to send the public key of the server in advance to the client?Can somebody please help with understanding this and its implementation?

Server code to encrypt:

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    RsaEncryption rsa;
    public HelloController()
    {
        rsa = new RsaEncryption();
    }
    public string Get()
    {
        string ret = "Hello World";
        ret = rsa.Encrypt(ret);
        return ret ;
    }
}
```

Client code to decrypt:

```
static async Task<string> GetProductAsync(string path)
{
    string product = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        product = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        product = rsa.Decrypt(product);
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this without sending it over the wire, like a little Console app?  Please read [mcve]

Comment: my client is a console app whereas my server is a WebApi project hosted locally.

Comment: So when you wrote this in a [mcve] such as all in a test console app, or .net fiddle to rule out any other factors. What did you find?

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm sorry,I didn't understand your question.I just want to know how to send my client's public key to my server for encryption.